# D3.js: How to change the position of a text in one single node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to change the position of a text in the root node to be visible.
I have a D3 structure and I would like to be able to point one single root node and change the text position. My root node text is not visible and I would like to put it underneath and showed.

I'm showing here a screenshot of my issue:

[image]

Comment: Consider using `dx` and `dy` attributes for the svg `text` element

Comment: Yes, but how I point only that root node? I want to change only on the root node that the issue I have.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, if your root node has a specific id or class, then select it and set the dx,dy. If you cannot do that and is using the inbuilt d3 nest, than add to your data dx and dy and set dx, dy from there. Another way is to set your viewBox on the svg to a value like "-50 0 "+width+height to allow root node to show. I can keep going on for an hour, without seeing your script, I can only guess.

Comment: Could you take a look at my scripts and tell me what you think?
https://pastebin.com/hF3ZqS2w
https://pastebin.com/zLC1PKp6

Comment: Ok let's try the easy one first, change  `var svg = d3.select(d3Div).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");` with  `var svg = d3.select(d3Div).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox","-25 -25 " + (width+25) + (height+25))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");`

Comment: I changed but still same issue as in the screenshot

Comment: add to the svg `.attr("preserveAspectRatio","none")`. And also is there a fiddle or something that I can see the behavior?

Comment: I added but no changes what can I do is a small screencast and share it with you.

Comment: That is very very unlikely, you are doing a typo somewhere. Check the answer.

Comment: You can take a look here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/60ah4u7cmwhrf85/TreeFlow.mov?dl=0

Comment: increase the padding value to something like 200, just to check: .attr("viewBox","-200 -200 "+(width+200)+" "+(height+200))

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var svg = d3.select(d3Div).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");
```

with

```
var svg = d3.select(d3Div).append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio","none")
    .attr("viewBox","-50 -50 "+(width+50)+" "+(height+50))
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");
```

Another mundane solution, As far as I remember tree returns a hierarchical data, where d.parent is null for the root. So if you have a place where you are setting the dy:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

replace the dy part with:

```
...
.attr("dy",function(d){!d.parent ? this.parentNode.getBBox().height : ".35em"})
.attr("dx",function(d){!d.parent ? this.parentNode.getBBox().width: ".35em"})
...
```

You specifically want to do this in the enter phase, after setting the text.A working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/7770988e/3/

in your case, there is no node update, so your best bet is to add the above 2 lines AFTER setting the text, so the the bbox will return the correct dimensions:

```
 node.append("text")
    //.attr("dy", 3)
    //.attr("fill", function(d) { return d3TextColour(d); })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return d3TextColour(d);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
      return d.children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      if (d.name.length > 15) {
        return d.name.substring(0, 12) + "..."
      } else {
        return d.name;
      }
    })
    .attr("dy",function(d){console.log(d.name === "root"); return d.name === "root" ? this.parentNode.getBBox().height : 3})
    .attr("dx",function(d){console.log(d.name === "root"); return d.name === "root" ? this.parentNode.getBBox().width : (d.children ? -8 : 8)});
```

Comment: Seems better but still 2 letters missing. If I understand well I need to increase the -50 to more and also the 50 to more to see more?

Comment: yes that is the problem. So your issue is not within d3, but the container. Check my comment, I suggested trying with a larger value like "-100 -100 "+(width+100)+" "+(height+100). That will fix it.

Comment: I did this way I see the root text but the children are cut at some point from the top now and not visible.

Comment: The problem is my text is very long and what I need is to have it under the node to be able to show it all. But only for the root node text

Comment: The first one should be OK, unless you have a very very long text. Try another solution I posted.

Comment: I have different places where I see dy dx but I don't know in which one I have to do this change?

Comment: start from line 58 in the first link you gave. Also add the dx underneath. Change ".35em" with your original value 3 if you want.

Comment: I added but now the nodes are overlapping everywhere on the text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170615/discussion-between-ibowankenobi-and-jakub).